# Using firebase authentication for a nodejs application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, authentication, firebase, firebase-security

I don't know if this will work out, or is it the right thing to do.

I have created an angularjs application and used firebase to provide my application a "backend", or to contain any data that my application needs.

Also I do not want to bother myself when dealing with authentication, and FirebaseSimpleLogin is just awesome tool for the job.

I could do:

```
resolve : {
   'isAuthenticated': isLoggedIn
}
```

in my routes so I would be able to prevent them from moving to secured routes. So there is no problem, I already have an authenticated user.

The problem is, i only used firebase to save user data and for auth, and nothing else.

Now I want to do some server tasks in my server, but I want only authenticated users to do that.

How would I determine that the user is authenticated in firebase?

Is this what [firebase token generator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-node) for.

Or should I just, create an authentication system using nodejs?

Comment: if your client do not directly communicate with firebase, you can authenticate only your server and on your node.js server you use any user authentication mechanism you like.

Comment: It sounds like you're not looking to replace Firebase's simple login protocols, in which case you won't need a custom token generator. Instead it sounds like you want your node application to re-use the logged on Firebase user and base your application's security around that. Is my understanding of what you're trying to accomplish correct?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are correct, I want to reuse user's logged in state,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [queue pattern](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue). Have the user write items to the queue, have the server respond to them.

The really great part of using Firebase as the API/middle-man is that the worker (i.e. server) does not need to worry about if the client has authenticated. [Security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/) take care of this.

Just write a rule to only allow logged-in users to write into the queue:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "queue": {
         "in": {
            // I can only write if logged in
            ".write": "auth !== null",
            "user_id": {
               // I can only write to the queue as myself, this tells the server which
               // out/ queue the user will be listening on
               ".validate": "auth.uid === newData.val()"
            }
         }, 
         "out": {
            "$userid": {
               // I can only listen to my out queue
               ".read": "auth.uid === $userid"
            }
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Now the user simply writes a record to in/ using push(), then listens on out/ until the server replies.

The server reads records out of the in/ queue, processes them, and writes them back to the out/user_id path.

No RESTful protocols, no express servers, no headaches.

Comment: i have a feeling that you are the one that will answer this one! hahaha