# Firebase with Electron, How to secure host?

Tags: node.js, firebase, localhost, firebase-authentication, electron

I'm considering using Firebase with my Electron App. Specifically I'd like to begin by using Firebase Authentication to sign users in to my app. I've done tons of research regarding the subject thus far, and my biggest concern remains that the domain I'd require for an authorized redirect would need to be localhost (Please correct me if I'm wrong). The Firebase interface sets localhost as an allowed domain by default, I assume just for developer testing, not for a live production environment (Again, please correct me if I'm wrong). The image below is the section of the Firebase Authentication interface that I'm referring to, for setting up authorized domains.

[image]

My question is this, in order to distribute an Electron application with access to Firebase, do I have to have the localhost domain authorized? As well, if I do have the localhost domain authorized, is this secure, in the context of couldn't malicious users set up their own localhost and redirect to an unintended page, giving them the ability to freely add data to Firebase databases?

If there's an alternate, more secure option than authorizing the localhost, what are my options?

I've read in plenty of places that the bulk of Firebase security comes in the form of setting applicable rules on who can read and write to the database. Namely [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303809/using-firebase-authentication-for-a-nodejs-application?rq=1) gives some good oversight on the topic. But I'm a firm believer that if there are extra security measures that can be taken, then always take them, so long as they don't diminish the quality of the application.

Am I being too paranoid, or is this the right approach? Thanks in advance! Any advice or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: In your post you're talking about using Firebase Auth, but in the end you mention "Firebase security comes in the form of setting applicable rules on who can read and write to the database" -> have in mind that these rules are applied to the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) which is a different service from [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see many questions in your post, but I'll answer these two:

1. > My question is this, in order to distribute an Electron application
   >   with access to Firebase, do I have to have the localhost domain
   >   authorized?

   That's not something implied by Firebase. Having the localhost
   domain authorized is just for testing purposes when you're running
   your app locally before deploying to another domain.
2. > If I do have the localhost domain authorized, is this secure, in the
   >   context of couldn't malicious users set up their own localhost and
   >   redirect to an unintended page, giving them the ability to freely add
   >   data to Firebase databases?

   Yes, it is secure. You said you haven't started with Firebase yet,
   but when you do, you'll find out that you need to download the [service credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk)
   to be able to use the SDK in your app. Only you have access to these credentials. That's why other users can't setup their own localhost and access your authentication system.

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I've set it as the accepted answer because it seems to answer my questions. But I am still a little confused, hopefully you could help clear up a bit more? The service credentials that you speak of, aren't those still embedded in the source code? I feel like I might be misunderstanding something. If I distribute my Electron application with the service credentials embedded within the source code, what prevents a user from copying that information and using it for their own purposes? Thanks in advance! I apologize if this should be obvious..

Comment: The credential is a JSON file that you're importing in your source code. And you're using node.js, so this file shouldn't be accessible to anyone since it is stored on the server-side. I've never really developed a NodeJS app, but I guess there might be some techniques to prevent this file from being accessed from outside the server.

Comment: I suppose that's the issue with Electron. There is no server, it's like opening a file in chrome. That's not to say that I can't make a server and host it through a third party. Maybe just display the information through the Electron interface. But I feel like that defeats the purpose of using a DAS. Anyway, I appreciate your assistance, thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant outside Electron.

Comment: @AustinFish This might be helpful service credential are required for the admin SDK not the client side framework. Since you probably don't want to give your user admin capabilities you don't need these in the distributable app.